# environnement variables in system wide cron

Tags: python, shell, docker, cron, debian

I recently had to switch from an python **Alpine** based image to the so called [python:3.7.2-slim](https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags&page=4) (**Debian based**). My cron jobs do not seem to work anymore because **environment variables** are no longer available to cron. I came to this conclusion with this test script:

```
# run.py
import os, sys
with open("/var/log/lastlog", "a") as f:
    try:
        user = os.environ['INFLUXDB_USER'] or "None"
        f.write("I am running python as {} with {}\n".format(user, sys.version_info[:3]))
    except Exception as e:
        f.write("I failed: {}\n".format(str(e)))
```

and this crontab

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
# ADDED 
*/1 * * * * root . /root/.bashrc; python3.7 /usr/src/collector/run.py
*/1 * * * * root echo 'hi' >> /var/log/lastlog
```

Exceptions show that `INFLUXDB_USER` is not found when the script is run by cron but is found when run manually (or when asking `os.environ['INFLUXDB_USER']` in a python shell).

### What I tried

- sourcing the command ( by adding `. /root/.bashrc;` in front of it (also tried `. /root/.profile;`))
- putting it in a **distinct shell script** right after `source /root/.bashrc`
- using absolute PATH
- used a bash login to run the command [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158930)
- move the instructions in a `cron.d`
- add the command with `crontab-e` rather than editing `/etc/crontab` directly

Since ENV VARIABLES are not defined in `/etc/environment`, I am not sure whether this "**System Wide Cron**" could access them in any way. I find this cron quite confusing compared with the `/etc/crontab/root` I had to edit in Alpine (which worked straight away). How do you handle this "*system wide crontab*"? Is this a specificity of Debian?

**Edit**

- version: `cron/oldstable,now 3.0pl1-128+deb9u1 amd64`
- env variable defined with Docker are stored in `/proc/1/environ` (but sourcing it did not change a thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only straightforward way I could find was to write directly the VARIABLES in `/etc/crontab` by slightly tweaking the `entrypoint.sh` of the Docker Image. Here is a way to add those after `SHELL=/bin/sh` with **sed**

```
sed -i "/SHELL=\/bin\/sh/a INFLUXDB_USER=$INFLUXDB_USER" /etc/crontab
sed -i "/SHELL=\/bin\/sh/a PROJECT_NAME=$PROJECT_NAME" /etc/crontab
sed -i "/SHELL=\/bin\/sh/a INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=$INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD" /etc/crontab
sed -i "/SHELL=\/bin\/sh/a INFLUXDB_DB=$INFLUXDB_DB" /etc/crontab

printf "3 */1 * * * root python /usr/src/collector/coin.py fetch cmc\n" >> /etc/crontab
printf "30 0 * * 4 root python /usr/src/collector/coin.py fetch gt --mode weekly\n" >> /etc/crontab

service cron restart
chmod 640 /etc/crontab
```

I am not very happy with it so any more elegant solution is welcome.